# How can i get AND clause in parse ios

Tags: ios, iphone, parse-platform, pfquery

i am using this [link](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries-compound/iOS) as a guide, but i can figure out how can i use AND clause for parse. It only defines OR clause in sample code.

if i were to convert it from SQL statement, it looks like this...

```
SELECT * FROM RemittanceTable WHERE beneCode = 'code' AND remittanceAmount = 500.00
```

For example in this code, i want to check if the code AND amount if correct before reading the data. But it validates with OR clause

```
PFQuery *beneCodeQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"RemittanceTable"];
[beneCodeQuery whereKey:@"beneCode" containsString:_beneCodeText.text];

PFQuery *amountQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"RemittanceTable"];
[amountQuery whereKey:@"remittanceAmount" equalTo:amount];

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:beneCodeQuery,amountQuery,nil]];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        for (PFObject *object in objects) {
            NSLog(@"%@", object);

            [self resignAllResponder];
            _paymentDetailsImage.frame = CGRectMake(_paymentDetailsImage.frame.origin.x, _paymentDetailsImage.frame.origin.y, _paymentDetailsImage.frame.size.width, paymentModeOrigHeight);
            _detailsView.alpha = 1;

        }
    }}}];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each time you add a constraint, it is implicitly using AND:

```
[query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:@"admin"];
[query whereKey:@"location" equalTo:@"USA"];
```

translates to "username == 'admin' AND location == 'USA'"

**UPDATE**

Your specific case as an example:

```
PFQuery *beneCodeQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"RemittanceTable"];
[beneCodeQuery whereKey:@"beneCode" containsString:_beneCodeText.text];
[beneCodeQuery whereKey:@"remittanceAmount" equalTo:amount];

NSArray *result = [beneCodeQuery findObjects];
```

Comment: it works fine. i'll tag this as an answer after two minutes, as it prompts to me to accept this answer in two minutes

Comment: Thanks. Glad you got what you need

Comment: this is absolutely not true in my case.  I am doing this exact thing on 2 string fields and just by matching one of them it returns the record.

Comment: @Jesse, that is not possible. You have some oddity in your code or data. From the docs: "You can give multiple constraints, and objects will only be in the results if they match all of the constraints. In other words, it's like an AND of constraints." https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries/iOS

Comment: hi, what if i have multiple keywords in one field. means in you example i need "username" must having "im" and "ran". then query should return "imran","imran123".... but not "imra" or "mran"....etc please guid me

Answer (score 0):

I came across this answer by Héctor Ramos on Parse.com forum recently:

> You can indeed have multiple constraints on a single query, which will be treated as an AND. Having the same constraint more than once for the same key, is not supported. In this case you have two whereKey:equalTo: constraints over "members", so only the last one is being considered.
>
> Instead you'll want to use whereKey:containsAllObjectsInArray:.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Conversation"];
[query whereKey:@"members" containsAllObjectsInArray:@[aFriend.data, [PFUser currentUser]]];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {...}];
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: it is only for 1 field. as you can see, i'm comparing here two fields.